# Issue with "M" in BEM with React CSS Module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, classname, bem

I'm trying to incorporate BEM with my project. It was fine with the element part (block__element), but I'm keep getting an error when I try to name the modifiers (block__element--modifier). Below is my code including the error, the mixin I wrote for BEM, the SCSS snippet, and the setting in my IDE (webstorm). I tried all different things (not using mixin, etc.) but nothing seems to work. Please help!

[image: React]

[image: Sass]
[image: Mixin][image: error][image: WS Setting]

Comment: You can't use `-` in javascript identifiers because this will be interpreted as an subtraction operator. If the name of an object key contains invalid characters for an identifier you can only access it with square brackets, e.g `styles['card__content--icn']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you using modifiers is incorrect at all.

Modifiers are not sub-elements, they are modifiers for blocks and elements and can't be used without mother-eneities.

Correct:

- `<div class="b">`
- `<div class="b__e">`
- `<div class="b b--m1 b--m2">`
- `<div class="b__e b__e--m b__e--m2">`

Incorrect:

- `<div class="b--m1">`
- `<div class="b__e--m">`

The reason why it works like this is the nature of modifiers — they are things very close to interfaces or mix-ins, they can't be used without blocks like interfaces can't be used without classes.

Read more about modifiers here: https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#modifier

Another thing you should not repeat BEM-structure in your HTML-structure.

So this is Incorrect:

```
<div className={styles.card__content}>
    <div className={styles['card__content--icn']}>Icon</div>
    <div className={styles['card__content--sub']}>Test</div>
</div>
```

And this is Correct:

```
<div className={styles.card__content}>
    <div className={styles.card__icon}>Icon</div>
    <div className={styles.card__sub}>Test</div>
</div>
```

See https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#can-i-create-elements-of-elements-block__elem1__elem2

---

If you interesting in using BEM with React you should take a look at bem-react-core — tiny library that helps you generating BEM-classes, provides runtime, etc.:

- https://github.com/bem/bem-react-core/

Comment: You're amazing. My understanding of BEM was very limited. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you. :-) I'm glad to help.

Comment: How to combine multiple classes? `<button className={styles['button button--alert']}>button</button>` doesn't seem to work..

Comment: Manually: `className={[styles['button'], styles['button--alert']].join(' ')}`

Comment: Magically: `b('button').m('alert')` See: https://github.com/awinogradov/easy-bem-naming https://github.com/azproduction/b_

Answer (score 1):

You can use another object form of record. Try something like this: `className={styles['card_content--icn']}`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! Could you explain why the dot notation wouldn't work?

Comment: It's because the js engine accepts "-" as a mathematical minus, so you have to pass a key to object as a string